# fSpy Camera Misalignment? Floorplan alignment to a 3D representation

Tags: modeling, camera, svg, fspy

Basically I'm having problems trying to align my floorplan to a 3D representation floorplan. I'm using fSpy and I'm pretty sure my lines match up closely. It's off by quite a lot in the second photo. I drew the floorplan in illustrator from real snippets of the actual masterplans.

[image: This is the alignment in fSpy]
[image: The camera that fSpy exports doesn't match the floorplan]
[image: I know the 2d floorplan I drew is accurate because they're from a floorplan snippet from the real floorplan]

Comment: I've had a look around.. I'm not sure fSpy can handle orthographic images. Your reference-axis lines seem to have no vanishing points? A match might just be setting up an orthographic camera at the right angle. Is this drawing isometric?  If so, there's help out there.